# Struts action name wildcard match has OGNL security vulnerabilities in fortify scan

Tags: struts2, action, fortify

Default action is defined as below in struts.xml.
Fortify scan complains about "*" matching saying - 
"Using wildcards (*) in Struts 2 action names allows evaluation of action names as OGNL expressions effectively allowing an attacker to modify system variables like Session or execute arbitrary commands on the server."

```xml
<action name="*" class="XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.GenericAction">
    <result>{1}.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStacki18n" />
</action>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in Struts 2.3.14.3 (see https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-015.html).

The solution is to upgrade and fix your whitelisting.

---

Slightly related: pasting that into Google returned this on the first page of results; sometimes just searching the web will answer your questions.

Comment: But still I am confused about "fix your whitelisting" part - 
Will this solve the problem - 

<constant name="struts.allowed.action.names" value="[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[.\-_!/]*" />

-----
-----

<action name="[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[.\-_!/]*" class="XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.GenericAction">
    <result>{1}.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStacki18n" />
</action>